# CRUD приложение, документация Spring

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

Дали ковырять back-end на Spring(e) в компании, вот пытаюсь теперь разобраться с проектом и документацией.
Открыл документацию, а тут вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как новичку понять, что читать?). Мне нужно реализовать CRUD приложение, табличка в ней данные, которые можно удалить, добавить, изменить. 
А там вон сколько и Spring Boot, Spring Data Rest, Spring Security и тд. 
Вот дерево проекта, то есть контроллеры, дто, сервисы, энтити.
Связь с БД и работа с ней осуществляется с помощью liquibase.
Здесь просто тебе дают таск, ты копируешь уже реализующий и фиксишь баги и вауля ГОТОВО. Но потом что-нибудь другое сломаешь и не знаешь как сделать. А помочь совсем никому, у всех сроки и все заняты, но я не жалуюсь, я всё это понимаю и пытаюсь всё сделать сам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня подход таков, что я должен каждую мелочь знать что да как, вот поэтому хочу хорошо разобраться чем копипастить. 
Как сказали мне на учёбе: "Копипаст хуже зла")).
Про Spring много не знаю, прочитал только в википедии информацию и пару статейк на Хабре.
Так делал по гайдам в официальной документации, всё круто, всё легко, всё получается, а вот в большом проекте трудно ориентироваться. 
Единственное покамись что понял, так это то, что нужно начинать со Spring Boot ибо это уже готовое стартовое приложение.
1 Вопрос: С чего начинать читать документацию официальную Spring.
2 Вопрос: Может кто-нибудь знает где можно почитать информацию о контроллёрах, dto, entity, repository, services, как у меня в проекте, чтобы мог на примерах посмотреть и сделать сам (если русская то вообще круто будет). Заранее спасибо

Comment: Мой личный подход: придумываете проект, пытаетесь его реализовать. Начинаете от простого вывода Hello World по адресной строке, далее идёте к таким вещам как работа с БД и авторизация и т.д. По ходу написания проекта изучаете как реализовать то, что вам в данный момент требуется.

Comment: Начинать изучать Spring нужно со [Spring Core](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework). Spring Boot это просто упрощение конфигурации. На мой взгляд, начинать изучать Spring лучше всего по книге (например, [Spring in Action](https://www.amazon.com/Spring-Action-Covers-4/dp/161729120X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1548051013&sr=8-2&keywords=spring+in+action)). Книга даст фундаментальное понимание фреймворка, а после этого можно начать читать документацию.

Comment: @notaProgrammer есть ли это книга или материал из этой книги на русском?

Comment: @notaProgrammer посмотрел и нашел 5 издание. Его лучше начать читать или 4 издание?

Comment: не плохой результат. еще месяц назад человек спрашивал что такое switch, а сейчас уже в компании Spring разрабатывает...

Comment: @michael_best да я с основами давно был знаком, просто глубоко копал, как их можно по-другому использовать и тд. Но пробелы были не спорю :). Сижу 24 на 7, спасибо что помогали, я вас помню :)

Comment: в тему: у меня самый лучший ответ - это ответ на ваш вопрос, получил 7 голосов, а вы приняли другой)

Comment: @michael_best Вспомнил, я изменил. Я забыл тогда, извиняюсь :)

Comment: Спасибо))) крайне благодарен)

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван А я бы посоветовал сначала изучить что такое Java EE ибо Spring в вебе базируется на нем. Ну и потом уже Spring Core и т.д.

Comment: @Tsyklop не нужно вводить человека в заблуждение. Spring базируется на сервлетах и фильтрах (да это Java EE, но лишь ее малая часть).

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван конечно лучше читать 5 издание. На счет перевода на русский не знаю, лучше читать на англ, так как программисту он в любом случае нужен (любая документация будет на англ).

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван еще забыл указать [замечательные видео-уроки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GB8k2-Egfv0&list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7). С них прям можно и начать.

Comment: @notaProgrammer я английский хорошо учил и на курсы ходил, но тут технический, который я вообще не знаю. Прочитал 100 страниц за сегодня и всё равно ничего не понял :). Но я буду каждое слово выписывать и учить так хоть сдвиги пойдут.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван поверь с этого все начинали и я в том числе ;) P.S. Помню когда начал читать на англ, не знал как переводиться "application". Вот так вот)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начинайте читать со `Spring in Action`, разберитесь с тем что такое `Dependency Injection` и `IoC`, потому что спринг, это именно `Dependency injection framework`. 
После этого, нужно понять, на какие логические слои (`layers`) обычно делятся приложения. Это такие уровни как, `DAO`, `Service Layer`, `REST Controllers`, `Model/DTO`. Точно не знаю, но возможно это можно будет найти в книге указанной выше. Как эти уровни между собой взаимодействуют и какую логику не нужно выносить за их границы. 
К примеру, делать прямой запрос в базу данных с контроллера, это не лучшая практика и в перспективе приведет к макаронному коду. 
Обращайте сначала внимания только на `Spring Core` и `Spring MVC`. Секюрити,а тем более `Spring Data`, пока вы не научитесь работать с базой более близко вам не нужны. Разберитесь с тем что такое контекст спринга и контейнер бинов. 
Так же не рекомендую начинать со `Spring Boot`, а пробовать конфигурировать свой проект самому, чтобы понять, почему все работает именно так + это даст общее понимания работы самого спринга.